# Cannot boot into Ubuntu after installing Windows

Tags: grub2, windows

I have installed Windows 8.1 after installing Ubuntu. `grub` is not loading so I lose access to Linux.

I am unable to boot from my installation disk, as my system just instantly reboots without any confirmation or chance to stop it.

Is there a way I can restore access to my Linux installation?

Comment: What do you mean when you say the system instantly reboots? Do you mean that you successfully boot to the installation media, but it reboots immediately from there? Do you mean that selecting reboot from Windows causes a reboot that's too fast?

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex No. It's shutting down while trying to load setup GUI